# Retrieving a single record in ember

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

Long story short, I'm trying to retrieve a single record in ember (more specifically a user object that contains vital information following a login).

However, when I try to use `@store.find "user", query`, I receive `Error: Assertion Failed: The response from a findQuery must be an Array, not undefined`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are querying for `user` type and `query` from above is a POJO your code may look like so:

```
var usersPromise = store.find('user', {foo:'bar', bla: 'baz'});
```

The response from your server would look something like this (note: `users` is plural), this is why you're receiving the error ([ember.js Error: Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560929/ember-js-error-assertion-failed-the-response-from-a-findall-must-be-an-array/22561488#22561488)).

```
{
  users: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Santa Clause'
    }
  ]
}
```

Since you are querying by POJO Ember assumes there are 0+ results.  After the promise has resolved you can return the first object from that, since the collection will only have one.

```
usersPromise.then(function(users){
  return users.get('firstObject');
});
```

so in your case you would probably do something like this

```
this.store.find('user', {foo:'bar', bla: 'baz'}).then(function(users){
  return users.get('firstObject');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm surprised this isn't better documented!